# Parameterized Cypher query and Neo4J JDBC prepared statements

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

I have a parameterized cypher query which looks similar to this -

```
FOREACH (rel IN {relations} | 
match (src:Biz_Table{db_name:rel.sdb_name, table_name:rel.stname}),(dest:Biz_Table{db_name:rel.ddb_name, table_name:rel.dtname})

create (src) - [:Connects { name:rel.name, values:[rel.values],
rel.key_field1:rel.key_field1_values, rel.key_field2:rel.key_field2_values}] -> (dest) )
```

now I want to pass {relations} variable from JDBC prepared statement - which will be array of objects I want to loop through.

Comment: Put your code into code blocks and make it easier to read. It will help you get an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use preparedstatement.setObject of a list of maps

Comment: HI Michael, thanks for your response. What does each map represents here ? why do we need to send list<Map<>> can you please elaborate?

Comment: ANd also what will be key for each entry in the map?

Comment: Hi Michael, your suggestion worked. I added each item as a map and added them to list. But my query needed little modification before making it work perfectly. change was - ` WITH {1} as relations  
unwind relations as rel  
match (src:Biz_Table{db_name:rel.sdb_name, table_name:rel.stname}), (dest:Biz_Table{db_name:rel.ddb_name, table_name:rel.dtname}) \
create (src) - [a:Connects { name:rel.name, values:[rel.values], key_field1:rel.key_field1, key_field1_value:rel.key_field1_value, key_field2:rel.key_field2, key_field2_value:rel.key_field2_value}] -> (dest)
`